# Python 3.3.3 what happened when re.compile('e') and re.compile('\e')?

Tags: python, regex

Update 1:

```
>>> '\e'
'\\e'
```

Above shows that Python literal parser treats `'\e'` as two literals `\` and `e`. Am I right?  If so,
`re.compile('\e')` should also follow this rule **first**. i.e., It should match two lierals `\` and `e`. Like this:

```
>>> re.findall('\e','\e\e')
['\e', '\e']
```

If I am wrong, Why?

original question:

For convenience I use **rer** to indicate the mechanism of python standard lib re module.

I have read related articles in python doc. I know the warning "it’s highly recommended that you use raw strings for all but the simplest expressions". But I just want to know if I don't use raw strings , how will the re.compile work. just take a look at this:

```
>>> A=re.compile('\e')
>>> B=re.compile('e')
>>> A==B
False
>>> re.findall(A,'eee')
['e', 'e', 'e']
>>> re.findall(B,'eee')
['e', 'e', 'e']
```

As you can see, there is nothing different between A and B when performing searching. Then:

Why '\e' can match string literal 'e'?

Can you find a string literals that will make differences?

Another question is why `re.compile('\\')` will raise errors. Note, this is a question about the re mechanism rather than how the re source code is written. Because I think:

Obviously `\\` means a literal backslash, why rer doesn't know this?  Why we need a pattern `\\\\` to match a literal backslash? Just look at this:

```
>>> re.findall('\n','\n')
['\n']
```

Perfectly works. However when you change `n` to `\`, rer raises erros. This is really hard for me to understand.

What will happen to rer if rer allow `\\` to match a literal backslash? Is it something like the basis of re doesn't exist? If so, can you give an example?

Thanks in advance. It has confused me for a long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `\e` and `e` are the same for the regular expressions. A `\` in a regular expression is used to indicate that the character following has a special meaning. You can find the list of valid special sequences [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), and `\e` is not one of them. So, `\` in front `e` is ignored.
2. When you say `\\` in your code, you actually say `\` in regular expression. We know that, `\` gives special meaning to the character following that. But when we say `\\`, there is no character following that. That's why it gives that error message. To actually match `\`, you need to escape the `\` like this `\\\\`. Or you can use [raw string notation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#raw-string-notation) like this

   ```
   re.compile(r'\\')
   print(re.findall(C, "\\"))
   ```

Quoting from http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

> Regular expressions use the backslash character ('\') to indicate
>   special forms or to allow special characters to be used without
>   invoking their special meaning. This collides with Python’s usage of
>   the same character for the same purpose in string literals; for
>   example, to match a literal backslash, one might have to write '\\'
>   as the pattern string, because the regular expression must be \, and
>   each backslash must be expressed as \ inside a regular Python string
>   literal.
>
> The solution is to use Python’s raw string notation for regular
>   expression patterns; backslashes are not handled in any special way in
>   a string literal prefixed with 'r'. So r"\n" is a two-character string
>   containing '\' and 'n', while "\n" is a one-character string
>   containing a newline. Usually patterns will be expressed in Python
>   code using this raw string notation.

Comment: I know the rules 'When you say \\ in your code, you actually say \ in regular expression'. I don't know why we can't say 'When you say \\ in your code, you also say \\ in regular expression'.

Comment: @Pythoner The `\\ ` is to actually escape `\ ` in python code. So, we are actually  passing `\ ` to the regular expression.

Answer (score 3):

There are two layers here: first, there's Python string literal syntax, and then there's the regular expression syntax.

`\e` doesn't have any special meaning in a Python string literal, so both characters get passed verbatim to the regular expression engine, where they match an `e` because that's what `\` means in that context: it removes any special meaning from the following character. (The fact that `e` doesn't have any special meaning in regexen to begin with doesn't mattter).

Comment: Yeah, this is just what I think. According to this logic, `re.compile('\\')` should match a literal backslash because the first \ removes any special meaning from the following \.